# how to get the Available Ram Memory we have throgh javascript

Tags: javascript, memory, ram

I  wanted to know how much ram Memory is consumed by the current opening tab
in browser
And the available ram memory we have

I am looking for a RAM Memory not the JS or heap memory
I wanted to show an alert to the user if his available Ram memory is low
if anyone have Idea how to achieve this in Javascript please let me know
Thanks

Comment: Is this within a browser or using NodeJS?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson - They mentioned the "current opening tab in browser" so I'm figuring browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder gotcha, good answer

Answer (score 3):

You can't get that information from browser-hosted JavaScript. The closest you can get is the [Device Memory API](https://w3c.github.io/device-memory/#sec-device-memory-js-api) (see also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory)) which is experimental and intentionally imprecise and may even lie to you.¹ But even that doesn't give you what you've said you want, it just tells you the total amount of memory the device has (maybe, if it's not lying).

---

¹ *"...may even lie to you."* - The API clamps the values to *"...protect the privacy of owners of very low- or high-memory devices"* (MDN). The exact bounds values used are up to the implementation in the browser; the spec [currently recommends](https://w3c.github.io/device-memory/#computing-device-memory-value) a lower bound of 0.25[GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) and an upper bound of 8GiB.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder
Thanks for your Response, you are right  Device Memory Api gives the total RAM memory but not the consumed and remaining Memory I don't know what else I can do to achieve this task, I am having large amount of processing and other stuff in my App 
which will consume large amount of memory  for that purpose I want to show an alert or handle other process in that case if happen